# Python - Add OR Subtract N *Business* Days from Date Input

Tags: python, datetime, timedelta

I am trying to make a function that will add **or** subtract **business** days to a date. I have a form that contains the following:

- Input: DatePicker (datetime)
- Input: NumberOfDays (int)
- Button: CalendarDays/BusinessDays
- Output: FinalDate from calculation

**HURDLE:** I can ONLY use datetime and timedelta - no numpy, pandas, etc. The code below works, however, it only works for adding business days.

**GOAL:** If possible, I would like to use a single function that will calculate **business** days, and use a positive or negative integer to determine if the **business** day calculation is addition or subtraction. The code below works, however, it only works with a positive integer input, and only adds business days.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

def bizday_calc_func(self, start_date, num_days):
    my_start_date = start_date
    my_num_days = num_days
    while my_num_days > 0:
      my_start_date += timedelta(days=1)
      weekday = my_start_date.weekday()
      if weekday >= 5:
        continue
      my_num_days -= 1
    return my_start_date
```

Comment: Can you write a version that can *only* go backwards?

Comment: Yes, I can use a function that subtracts the business days as well. Would like a single one that does both, but at this point, I'll take anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like a small tweak to your routine would do the trick:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

def bizday_calc_func(self, start_date, num_days):
    my_start_date = start_date
    my_num_days = abs(num_days)
    inc = 1 if num_days > 0 else -1
    while my_num_days > 0:
      my_start_date += timedelta(days=inc)
      weekday = my_start_date.weekday()
      if weekday >= 5:
        continue
      my_num_days -= 1
    return my_start_date
```

disclaimer: untested.